# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03a3' in position 409: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, jira-rest-api

I am running Python code to pull the issues from JIRA. This code is provided by Atlassian and they are using JiraOne Library.

In the Config.Json file we have the following information.

```
{
"user": "prince@example.com",
"password": "<APITOKEN_HERE>",
"url": "https://nexusfive.atlassian.net"
}
```

Below is the Python code I am running.

```
from jiraone import LOGIN, issue_export
import json

file = "config.json"
config = json.load(open(file))
LOGIN(**config)

jql = "project in (AB, BC, IT, IP) order by created DESC"
issue_export(jql=jql)
```

I am getting below error message and no clue on how to resolve this.

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Downloading issue export in CSV format.
<Response [200]> OK ::downloading issues at page: 0 of 9
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\User123\Desktop\PBI Files\Python Scripts\untitled10.py", line 12, in <module>
    issue_export(jql=jql)

  File "C:\Users\User123\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jiraone\reporting.py", line 2189, in export_issues
    file_writer(

  File "C:\Users\User123\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jiraone\reporting.py", line 3223, in file_writer
    f.write(content)

  File "C:\Users\User123\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03a3' in position 409: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: What version of `jiraone` do you have?

Comment: I have latest v.0.7.4

I got the info from this link https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-articles/How-to-export-all-issues-from-Jira-via-API/ba-p/2126063

Comment: By any chance are you running it on a `windows` machine?

Comment: You can take a look at the message that was sent by [Prince Nyeche](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-articles/How-to-export-all-issues-from-Jira-via-API/ba-p/2126063) on `Oct 31, 2022`. They talk about a work around to a very similar issue that you're having.

Comment: Yes it is Windows machine.. One of the user added a code in between and resolved this issue but since I am a beginner in Python I dont know where to insert the code.

file_writer(folder, file_name,
content=issues.content.decode('utf-8').encode('cp850','replace').decode('cp850'),
mark="file", mode="w+")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow the fix provided by [Prince Nyeche](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-articles/How-to-export-all-issues-from-Jira-via-API/ba-p/2126063) you have to do the following. Open the file `C:\Users\User123\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jiraone\reporting.py` in your text editor. Go to line 2189. It should look like this:

```
     file_writer(
            folder,
            file_name,
            content=issues.content.decode(encoding, errors=errors),
            mark="file",
            mode="w+",
        )
```

Add the suggested edit:

```
content=issues.content.decode('utf-8', errors="replace"),
```

Save your file. Then try your `untitled10.py` code again.